# Please help: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tried everything, so now I'm asking for help.

> NoMethodError in Jobs#index Showing
>   /Users/sillaspoulsen/Desktop/Coderstravel/app/views/jobs/index.html.erb
>   where line #15 raised:
>
> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
>
> " <% @jobs.each do |job| %> "

Here is my git if that helps: https://github.com/SillasPoulsen/coders

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `JobsController`, change

```
  def index
    @job = Job.all
  end
```

To

```
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all  ## plural jobs
  end
```

You are setting the instance variable as `@job` in `index` action and using `@jobs` (Notice plural) in `index.html.erb` which obviously would be nil. So, you get the error as `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

**UPDATE**

> it gives me the error NoMethodError in Jobs#index- " undefined method
>   `description' for #" "<%= job.description
>   %>"

`jobs` table has a field named `discription` and you are accessing `description` which does not exist in `jobs` table. Hence, the error.

Comment: oh thank you so much but when I do that, it gives me the error NoMethodError in Jobs#index- " undefined method `description' for #<Job:0x00000101964400>" "<td><%= job.description %></td>"

Comment: Read `UPDATE` section in my answer.